# X-Cart - Xtreme Gear template - Footer area

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to modify a few links in the footer area of my website.  The site us running X-Cart  using the Xtreme Gear template and the footer.tpl shows a reference to the following code:

```
{$xg_config.footer_secured}
```

However, I'm having a heck of a time trying to find where the referenced code is located.  Does anyone have any ideas as to where I could look?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've tried looking in the copyright.tpl, bottom.tpl, config.tpl, etc, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is....it is located in the database, not in the source code.
Footer_secured refers to a column in one of the database tables.  Search the database for that column if you're having the same problem and you will find it.